# How to parse an eXist XQuery response with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml, exist-db

I am trying to find an easy way to parse an **eXist response** with php without installing third party classes.

This is the type of response that I would like to parse :

```
<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
  <exist:collection name="xData" path="/db/SBXXX/00000000-00000000/sapData" created="2010-07-15T16:12:09.135-05:00">
    <exist:resource name="xDataData1.xml" size="1565" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-20T23:42:09.584-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData10.xml" size="805" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:27:09.614-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData11.xml" size="806" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:27:22.005-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData12.xml" size="1565" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:42:15.768-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData13.xml" size="805" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:57:09.749-05:00"/>
  </exist:collection>
</exist:result>
```

I am trying with the **simplexml_load_string** php function but I get back an empty SimpleXMLElement object with no errors.

I would like to get out of this response the list of XML files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath is the most "correct" way to access those attributes:

```
$xml = '<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
  <exist:collection name="xData">
    <exist:resource name="xDataData1.xml"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData10.xml"/>
  </exist:collection>
</exist:result>
';

$dom = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('exist', 'http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist');

$nodes = $xpath->query('exist:collection/exist:resource');
if (!$nodes->length)
  exit('No nodes found');

$items = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node)
  $items[] = $node->getAttribute('name');

print_r($items);
```

Which produces this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xDataData1.xml
    [1] => xDataData10.xml
)
```

Answer (score 1):

set the namespace, and use the xpath:

```
    $xml = '<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
  <exist:collection name="xData" path="/db/SBXXX/00000000-00000000/sapData" created="2010-07-15T16:12:09.135-05:00">
    <exist:xmlObject name="xDataData1.xml" size="1565" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-20T23:42:09.584-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData10.xml" size="805" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:27:09.614-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData11.xml" size="806" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:27:22.005-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData12.xml" size="1565" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:42:15.768-05:00"/>
    <exist:resource name="xDataData13.xml" size="805" created="1969-12-31T18:00:00.000-06:00" last-modified="2010-09-21T01:57:09.749-05:00"/>
  </exist:collection>
</exist:result>';
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xmlObject->registerXPathNamespace('e','http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist');
var_dump($xmlObject->xpath('//e:resource'));
```